In JsDoc, how do I make the @return type of my function the type of a local variable set in child class?
Using this question as a reference:
jsDoc : How do I make the @return type of my method the type of a local variable from it?
How do I accomplish this using an extended class?
class Parent {
  static Settings;

  /**
   * Gets settings
   * @param {string} userId
   * @returns {typeof this.Settings}
   */
  static get(userId) {
    //Get settings
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
  static Settings = ChildSettings;
}

Visual studio intellisense does not seem to pick up on this (the overridden properties are not properly updated with the correct type when overidden in a child class) even though the code works during runtime and a ChildSettings object is returned when the function is called.
While it works and it's a minor annoyance not having intellisense I would like to fix it if it's possible so I don't have to check manually if I typed the property names of the settings correctly every time.
It does work if I add a @type tag on the Settings property in the Parent class but that locks it to one type, and I have to support an expanding list of ChildObjects each with different properties.
I also tried
JSDoc - How do I document a static method in a superclass that returns an instance of its subclass? and that works, but it's returning the class of the Child and not the ChildSettings. I don't fully understand @template T and @this {T} so I'm not sure if it's even possible doing it that way.
I'm using javascript, not typescript

You can do it by generic this which should extend Parent
class Parent {
  static Settings;

  /**
   * @template {typeof Parent} T
   * @this {T}
   * @param {string} userId 
   * @returns {T['Settings']}
   */
  static get(userId) {
    return this.Settings;
  }
}

